# How do I return an array containing the elements which do not match a given parameter in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

> Write a function called "removeElement".
>
> Given an array of elements, and a "discarder" parameter,
>   "removeElement" returns an array containing the items in the given
>   array that do not match the "discarder" parameter.
>
> Notes:
>   * If all the elements match, it should return an empty array.
>   * If an empty array is passed in, it should return an empty array.

I thought this would be the solution:

```
  function removeElement(array, discarder) {

    var newarr = array.filter(function(cv, i, a){
      if (array == []) {
        return [];
      } else if (cv != discarder ) {
        return  cv;
      } 
    });
      return newarr;
  }
```

But I get this error:

> return_an_array_with_all_booleans_not_matching_discarder
>      return an array with all booleans not matching discarder

I thought this would then work, because initially I didn't add the clause to factor in if all values were equal to discarder.

```
function removeElement(array, discarder) {

    var newarr = array.filter(function(cv, i, a){
      if ((array == []) || (cv == discarder)) { // added this expression to evaluate.
        return [];
      } else if (cv != discarder ) {
        return  cv;
      } 
    });
      return newarr;
  }
```

Comment: array.filter should return a boolean

Comment: 1. `array == []` will always be false. 2. Returning `[]` will be interpreted by the `filter()` function as `true` which means the current item will NOT be excluded from the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

> The **`filter()`** method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

needs a boolean (or at least a truthy/falsy) value to return, you could just return the check with the given `discarder` and return the comparison result.

The result is an array without the given value.

```
function removeElement(array, discarder) {
    return array.filter(function(value) {
        return value !== discarder;
    });
}
```

Comment: Ah I think I overlooked the component regarding the `boolean` in the documentation of filter. Looks like I was being too literal with what I wrote thinking that if the current value didn't pass the test it was sufficient enough to just return the cv...